# Get access token from OAuth2 using Identity framework in Asp .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, bearer-token

In Web Apis, I always use given below URL to get access token.

```
http://localhost:port/token
```

But I cannot find token in MVC project. I try to find it over internet but unfortunately, does not find any solution.

Comment: It's provided by middleware, it's not from a controller.

Comment: @DavidG can you please share any thing for reference. Moreover, I try to find it in Startup.Auth.cs and IdentityConfig.cs but find nothing.

Comment: There is no controller action or route that you will find that implements this.  What @DavidG is getting at is that this endpoint is handled internally by the middleware.

Comment: The best reference I could find - and even this may be incorrect - is here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs

Comment: After creating a new WebAPI project with "Individual User Account" authentication mode, open Startup.Auth.cs and check CofigureAuth method.
In the middle of the method there is a code block that created a new instance of OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions. That is the place where you can customize
the builtin OAuth server (specially TokenEndpointPath).

Answer (score 0):

The url/token is not reserved value, it's configurable in code in Startup.Auth.cs file in the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions for example :

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new OAuthCustomRefreshTokenProvider(),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            AccessTokenFormat = new TokenManager(),
        };
```

whatever value you specify in the TokenEndpointPath, it's used in the URL to retrieve the access/refresh tokens